# TYPO3 - create a website using the extension "Myleaflet"

Tags: leaflet, typo3

I need your help. I'm still a beginner working with TYPO3...

I want to create a interactive card with a leaflet.
Then I found an extension "Myleaflet" in TYPO3 ver. 10.4.21.
I installed the extension "Myleaflet" and included it in Template on my new website. (Also Fluid Styled Content + CSS)

Now I have to add page ID and so on.
Mybe, I have to write somethikng in setup.typoscript. But I don't know what I should write...

In a manual of Myleaflet:

> Import the extension from TER (TYPO3 Extension Repository) like any
> other extension. Create some pages as shown below.
>
> Pages for myleaflet On page ‘Ajax Map’ install plugin MyLeaflet (Map).
> Make sure you have installed jQuery on top of the page.
>
> On page ‘myleaflet’ or on your root page insert ‘Typoscript Include
> static’ (from extension) MyLeaflet (myleaflet). With the constant
> editor insert the desired settings of the extension like storage Pid,
> your page ID’s, jQuery options, path to templates etc.
>
> The data of tt_address and sys_categories is stored in page Data.
> Insert in the constant editor the correct “Default storage PID” of the
> tt_address records.
>
> Then insert at least one sys_category in the page Data. Now insert
> some tt_address data records with latitude and longitude values and
> assign them to sys_categories. The extension did not fetch the
> coordinates by itself like the mymap extension.
>
> To use your own mapIcons insert your mapIcons into the directory
> fileadmin/ext/myleaflet/Resources/Public/Icons. Insert in this
> directory your icons which then can be selected in your tt_address
> data records.
>
> When everything is ok - test it…

**With the constant editor insert the desired settings of the extension like storage Pid, your page ID’s, jQuery options, path to templates etc.**

1. What should I do this?
   I thought I should wirte like "page = PAGE" in setup.ts, but I don't know what I wirte there down.

**The data of tt_address and sys_categories is stored in page Data. Insert in the constant editor the correct “Default storage PID” of the tt_address records.**

2. Should I write PID in constant.ts?:

```
persistence {
   # cat=plugin.tx_myleaflet//a; type=string; label=Default storage PID
   storagePid = 
 }
```

I'm so sorry for my stupid question. Typoscript is still difficult for me...

Thank you for your help.

Adding:

I can see a content in frontend now with sitepackage:
[image]

I gave something in a textarea and pushed a button "suchen". But I doesn't work anything. Is it normal? or I didn't configure in constants well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all: Do not edit the files of an extension, look into the concept of a sitepackage extensions. More: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/tutorial-sitepackage/main/en-us/

Now to your questions:

1. The extension wants you to edit constants. Constants are values which are used in the TypoScript setup. You can find the Constants Editor in the "Template" module in TYPO3 backend (select box on top). There you can edit your constants and if you're finished, you can e.g. cut and paste it to your sitepackage constants file.
2. You should use the Constants Editor here as well. Your example looks like the file of the extension (which you should not change).

Hope it helps you to get forward.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! 
I included my sitepackage extension and now I can see a content of a myleaflet. But it seems to not work well....

In constants in backend I wrote this:
plugin.tx_myleaflet.view.templateRootPath = EXT:myleaflet/Resources/Private/Templates/
plugin.tx_myleaflet.view.partialRootPath = EXT:myleaflet/Resources/Private/Partials/
plugin.tx_myleaflet.view.layoutRootPath = EXT:myleaflet/Resources/Private/Layouts/

Do I have to other thing?

Comment: Maybe you missed some constants? You talked about `storagePid`. Is that set as well?

Comment: I gave "1" for storagePid, but it doesn't work. Maybe  I wrote false in constants. At first, what exactly should I write in constants of myleaflet? It lacks some knowledges about TypoScript with me....

Comment: You first need a sysfolder (that's a special page). There you create address and category records. The ID of that page should be set into the constants. Then the extension knows where to look at.

Comment: Thank you for your explain. My boss said I should make an extension by my self to learn TYPO3. So that I can't use this extension anymore, but I had learned something a little. Thanks for your help.