# What does sys_categories mean using Myleaflet in TYPO3?

Tags: leaflet, typo3, categories

I installed an extension "Myleaflet" in TYPO3 ver. 10.4.21.
My frontend display this message:

[image]

What does sys_categories mean in this case and how exactly can I insert a sys_categories?

I have some categories, but is this not the sys_categories to use by Myleaflet?:

[image]

Anyway, I show you also my constants.ts. Maybe there are some false code:

```
plugin.tx_myleaflet {
  view {
    # cat=plugin.tx_myleaflet/file; type=string; label=Path to template root (FE)
    templateRootPath = EXT:myleaflet/Resources/Private/Templates/
    # cat=plugin.tx_myleaflet/file; type=string; label=Path to template partials (FE)
    partialRootPath = EXT:myleaflet/Resources/Private/Partials/
    # cat=plugin.tx_myleaflet/file; type=string; label=Path to template layouts (FE)
    layoutRootPath = EXT:myleaflet/Resources/Private/Layouts/
    
        # customsubcategory=javascript=Javascript
        # cat=plugin.tx_myleaflet/javascript; type=boolean; label=Include jQuery core: Add jQuery core script. Turn it off (0), if jQuery is already added.
        includejQueryCore = 0

        # customsubcategory=css=CSS
        # cat=plugin.tx_myleaflet/css; type=string; label=CSS file
        cssFile = EXT:myleaflet/Resources/Public/CSS/myleaflet.css

        # cat=plugin.tx_myleaflet/javascript; type=string; label=jQuery library
        jQueryFile = EXT:myleaflet/Resources/Public/JavaScript/jquery-3.3.1.min.js

        # cat=plugin.tx_myleaflet/javascript; type=string; label=Javascript file
        javascriptFile = EXT:myleaflet/Resources/Public/JavaScript/myleaflet.js
    
  }
  persistence {
    # cat=plugin.tx_myleaflet//a; type=string; label=Default storage PID
    storagePid = 0
  }

    settings {
        # customsubcategory=leafletmaps=maps
        # cat=plugin.tx_myleaflet/leafletmaps; type=int; label=Result page ID: Result page ID
        resultPageId = 1

        # cat=plugin.tx_myleaflet/leafletmaps; type=int; label=Details page ID: Details page ID
        detailsPageId = 1

        # cat=plugin.tx_myleaflet/leafletmaps; type=int; label=Single view uid: Uid (not the pageId) for the singleView plugin
        singleViewUid = 1

        # cat=plugin.tx_myleaflet/leafletmaps; type=int; label=Result limit: Limit of results
        resultLimit = 300

        # cat=plugin.tx_myleaflet/leafletmaps; type=string; label=Initial map coordinates: Initial map coordinates
        initialMapCoordinates = 48,8

        # cat=plugin.tx_myleaflet/leafletmaps; type=string; label=Category select mode: [AND|OR] Default OR
        categorySelectMode = OR

        # cat=plugin.tx_myleaflet/leafletmaps; type=boolean; label=Marker clusterer: Enables the marker clusterer
        enableMarkerClusterer = 0

        # cat=plugin.tx_myleaflet/leafletmaps; type=string; label=Default languageUid: Use 0 in multi language sites to override selected language in Frontend and if tt_adress record are not localized. Leave it blank to use TYPO3 localization.
        defaultLanguageUid = 0
    }
}
```

Also, I realized that the filestructure of manual of Myleaflet and the one of the extension.

[image]

There is no Data-file anywhere else. Maybe shoud I ignore this manual? I can't get it anymore....

I refered these website, but I couldn't get them...

Myleaflet:
https://docs.typo3.org/p/wsr/myleaflet/1.2/en-us/AdministratorManual/Index.html

system categories:
https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/10.4/en-us/ApiOverview/Categories/Index.html

I don't have enough knowledge of programming and TYPO3.
I hope you can help me with easily explain. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [TYPO3 - create a website using the extension "Myleaflet"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70679241/typo3-create-a-website-using-the-extension-myleaflet/70679386) you posted a documentation part which says:

`The data of tt_address and sys_categories is stored in page Data. Insert in the constant editor the correct “Default storage PID” of the tt_address records`

You obviously need sys_categories in the same sysfolder the address records are.